# CSS: Wrap div exactly around checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, background-color

I would like to fit a div exactly around a checkbox. I am doing this because I want to use it to set a background color of the checkbox.

I've tried this, but the pink div sticks out below the checkbox.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/8fhyf/)

```
#checkbox{ margin:0px; 
           padding:0px;
           opacity:0.5;}

#checkbox_wrapper{ background:pink;
                  float:left;}

<div id = "checkbox_wrapper" >
      <input  type="checkbox" id = "checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to whoever made that jfiddle for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `line-height` to `0`, the default font size was setting the `height` as `20px`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/8fhyf/1/)

[image]

```
#checkbox_wrapper {
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    line-height:0;
}
```

PS cool trick, I'm going to use it in the future ;)

### Update

Here's another way to implementation, with no wrapper or class required. Unfortunately only works in IE9+, Chrome and Safari. [Apparently it's against the CSS 2.1 spec](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=241985).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/ppqt8/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    position:relative;
}
input[type=checkbox]:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background:pink;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks :) (I'll accept the answer when it allows me too - you were too fast!!)

Comment: I can't see the effect in the no-wrapper jsFiddle in Firefox 19.0.2 and Opera 12.14. It works in Safari 6.0.3 and Chrome 26.0.1410.43.

Comment: Updated, generated content on form elements is against CSS 2.1 apparently https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=241985 good catch.

Comment: Yea, I'm aware of that one but it isn't anything to do with this question.